# No route found for "GET /" in NGINX conf

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, configuration, location

(first at all, sorry for english it's not my native :/ )

I have a problem with my NGINX conf, I have 2 symfony2 projects in 2 folders. The first one is my root dir (www.mywebsite.com/) in my nginx conf and I would have the second like this www.mywebsite.com/secondwebsite.

The first website works fine on port 80 (with classic nginx config).

My second website works fine on the port 82 (www.mywebsite.com:82) for example with this conf :

```
server {
    listen 82;
    server_name mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.;
    root /var/www/project/dev/secondwebsite/web/;
    index app_dev.php;
    location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
            try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

But I get a problem when I try to access like this www.mywebsite.com/secondwebsite, all my symfony2 routes does not work (I get a 404 on each), I put my app_dev.php as index to get more details

Here is the conf of my nginx conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com;
    index app.php;
    root /var/www/project/dev/mywebsite/web;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.access.log;
    if ($http_host != "www.mywebsite.com"){
            rewrite ^ http://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
    location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location /secondwebsite/ {
            alias /var/www/project/dev/secondwebsite/web/;
            index app_dev.php;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index  app_dev.php;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include         fastcgi_params;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

I've search many times but nothing works, I really need help ^^